# C Memory leak with packetsender socket

Tags: java, c, sockets, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

Hi guys I'am trying to write  IP Spoofing featured packetsender shared library for SIP application with JNI usage, When I tried to Run application and invoked native methods there wasn't any problem in the beginnings but after a time I think memory leak occured with no trace and crashed the JVM, my C is code (below) is higly influenced by [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/sipp/patches/_discuss/thread/622a0eb6/e9ca/attachment/sipp-trunk-rawsockets-patch.txt) and here is my Method which I invoked with JNI can any one help me to find the leak?

```
int send_message(const char * sip_msg, const char * dest_ip, int dest_port, const char * spoofed_ip, unsigned int source_port){
unsigned int source_ip = 0;
srand(time(0));
if(source_port == 0){
    source_port = rand() % 65535;
}
//unsigned int source_port = 0;
struct ip *ip;
struct udphdr *udp;
unsigned char packet[65535];
int len;
unsigned int msg_len =strlen(sip_msg);

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

int sockfd;
if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0) {
    printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
    return 1;
}

const int on = 1;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &on, sizeof(on)) == -1) {
    perror("\n Error : Set Sock Opt \n");
    return 1;
}

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(dest_port);
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(dest_ip);

len = sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + msg_len;

if (len > sizeof(packet)) {
    printf("Failed to send1!\n");
    return -2;
}

ip = (struct ip*) packet;
udp = (struct udphdr *) (packet + sizeof(struct ip));
memcpy(packet+sizeof(struct ip)+sizeof(struct udphdr),sip_msg,msg_len);


ip->ip_v = 4;
ip->ip_hl = sizeof(struct ip) / 4; // no options
ip->ip_tos = 0;
ip->ip_len = htons(len);
ip->ip_id = 23;
ip->ip_off = 0;
ip->ip_ttl = 69;
ip->ip_p = 17;
ip->ip_src.s_addr = inet_addr(spoofed_ip);
ip->ip_dst.s_addr = inet_addr(dest_ip);

ip->ip_sum = checksum((unsigned char *) ip, sizeof(struct ip));

/*if (source_port == 0) {
    source_port = 5060;
}*/

udp->source = htons(source_port);
udp->dest = serv_addr.sin_port;
udp->len = htons((unsigned short) sizeof(struct udphdr) + msg_len);
udp->check = 0;

if (sendto(sockfd, packet, len, 0, (struct sockaddr *) (&serv_addr),
        sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1) {
    return -2;
    printf("Failed to send!\n");
}

    close(sockfd);


return 0;}
```

Comment: Have you tried libpcap wrapper library like http://jnetpcap.com/?  You can do this using the library without writing this low level code. i.e. no C code is required.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  I've heard it before but never used :) Can you send me some UDP examples with this library?

Comment: A quick google found https://gist.github.com/alexcheng1982/7108987 I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can find *a* leak, not necessarily *the* leak.

Consider what happens if e.g. `sendto` fails. The socket has been opened with `socket()`, but you are not closing it. You really need to `close` the socket for all code paths that can be taken. This, btw, is a case where the use of a `goto` might be a good idea.

Comment: So I'guess you're saying when **sendto** fails socket stays on open state when overtime  if too much **sendto** fail occurs then sockets stayed open and this causes memory leak I'm a right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. Not that I'm certain this is your leak, but it's still a problem you should fix. Fix also the other code paths in addition to `sendto` failure.